# [UITabBarController setSports:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b80e2b0

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I’m building an iOS app. I want pass array value from one view controller to another through segue.

While doing this i’m getting an error:

> [UITabBarController setSports:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7b80e2b0.

here is my code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sportsSelection"]) {
     Play *play=[segue destinationViewController];
     play.sports=selectedSports;//error break point is here.
     //sports and selected sports are NSMutableArray
   }
}
```

Comment: is Play is your UIViewController Class??

Comment: it is UITableViewController but its a part of uitabbarcontroller

Comment: [segue destinationViewController] returns UITabBarController in your case. And exception say that tabController class has no selector named "setSports."

Comment: that i got it but could you please help me that how i can fix this

Comment: Is "sports" a synthesized property in your "Play" controller?

Comment: @iAmd No "sports" is not synthesized property in "Play" controller

Comment: try making the "sports" a synthesized property and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the situation a bit clearer, you are getting the error because you are trying to call a method (`setSports:`) on a class that does not implement this method, this is exactly what the error message tells you:

> [UITabBarController setSports:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7b80e2b0.

Your `segue` apparently has a `UITabBarController` as destination, so it's clear that it does not know about the method `setSports:`, since this one is actually implemented in your custom view controller (apparently called `Play`?!).

Then, as Eike pointed out in his answer, you need to get `Play` from the `UITabBarController` which it is embedded in. That's why he suggested to use: `Play* p = ((UITabBarController*)segue.destinationViewController).viewControllers[0];`, it means that you should get the view controller at index *0* from your `UITabBarController`.

According to your comment, the view controller at index *0* is a `UINavigationController`, which (naturally) also does not respond to `setSports:`, because just like `UITabBarController` it is a class provided by Apple and doesn't know about this method.

Now, you need to find out where in this `UITabBarController` your custom view controller `Play` is located. Either it is a direct part of `UITabBarController` and you can find it by using Eike's approach and just modify the index from 0 to n (where n is the number of view controllers that the `UITabBarController` has hold of), or another option is that it is embedded in the `UINavigationController` that you received at index 0, so in that case you'd have to access the `UINavigationController`'s view controller stack (e.g. the array property `viewControllers` or just the one that is currently on top of the stack using `topViewController`).

**Edit**: I want to give you some extra information about what's going on in your code, especially related to Eike's answer:

From the information that you gave us in your question and in the commment to Eike's solution, we can assume the following code to be correct:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sportsSelection"]) {
   UITabBarController *tabBarController = [segue destinationViewController]; // the destination of the segue is your `UITabBarController`
   UINavigationController *navigationController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0]; // gets the first of the view controllers contained in your UITabBarController
   NSLog(@"view controllers in navigation controller: %@; top view controller: %@", navigationController.viewControllers, navigationController.topViewController); // print all view controllers managed by navigationController
}
```

**EDIT 2**: From your comment I can now assume the following code to be correct:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sportsSelection"]) {
   UITabBarController *tabBarController = [segue destinationViewController]; // the destination of the segue is your `UITabBarController`
   UINavigationController *navigationController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0]; // gets the first of the view controllers contained in your UITabBarController
    Play *controller = (Play *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    controller.sports=selectedSports;
    play.sports = selectedSports;
}
```

Comment: thanks @nburk by implementing your code or by nslog i'm getting Play as viewcontroller and topviewcontroller,but i found everywhere in code there is no setSports: method in the code.I'm not getting what to do next

Comment: I updated the answer, your `Play` view controller is the `topViewController` of the `UINavigationController` which you receive from your `UITabBarController`.  `setSports:` is the _setter_ for the property `sports` which you most likely declared in `Play` :)

Comment: Thanks @nburk your answer is very helpful for me, but i have done this by little change:                                            Play *controller = (Play *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        controller.sports=selectedSports;

Answer (score 0):

You need to `setSports:` to your view controller not the  `UITabBarController`.

```
Play* p = ((UITabBarController*)segue.destinationViewController).viewControllers[0];
p.sports = selectedSports;
```

Comment: thanks @Eike I have applied your code but getting the same error [UINavigationController setSports:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78f132b0

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of the related VCs from the storyboard please?

Comment: yep that would definetely help

Comment: @Daljeet you are not getting the _same_ error, this time it says that the unrecognized selector is sent to an instance of `UINavigationController` instead of `UITabBarController`